# How can I use Flask to integrate a chatbot created with TensorFlow into a website?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have recently started developing a chat bot with Tensor Flow. I already have a model that receives a question and outputs an answer.How do I use Flask to integrate my Tensor flow chat bot model into a website?

Could you please help me with this by suggesting blogs or your views on the above?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Tensorflow Serving. https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving

Answer (score 0):

In your backend python code, create 2 function, load() and predict()

1. load() can be used to load your tf model into memory, you only need to call load once for the model.
2. Once you get requests in from Flask, route it to call the predict() which will do the real inference with the model in load().

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please share any code for the above method you have mentioned. I am an absolute beginner to Flask integration. Please do help.

Comment: check this one: https://blog.keras.io/building-a-simple-keras-deep-learning-rest-api.html

Comment: Thanks Dong. I will look into it